# Any James Bond films that used a Ford Mustang?

Tags: james-bond, props

Are there any James Bond films in the "canon" other than "Goldfinger" where one of the principals used a Ford Mustang in a high performance scene?

Comment: This question sponsored by Ford Mustang! Still a thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Sean Connery drives a Mustang down the Las Vegas strip in 1971's *Diamonds are Forever*. See [this post on the cars of James Bond](http://www.007james.com/articles/list_of_james_bond_cars.php) for a description of the scene.

[image]

Connery also gets taken for a ride in a Mustang in *Thunderball* in a scene taking place in the Bahamas.

[image]